# how to start an activity in an apk without installation?

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

I have a demand like this ,i wanna start an activity in an apk files,but i don't want to invoke installation.just load the classes and resources in apk directly.

here is my code
but the activity is not initialized correctly.

```
     DexClassLoader dLoader = new DexClassLoader( APK_PATH,"/mnt/sdcard",null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());  

        PackageInfo pInfo;
          pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(APK_PATH, 1);
          if ((pInfo.activities != null) && (pInfo.activities.length > 0))
          {


              clientClass = dLoader.loadClass(pInfo.activities[0].name);    

              clientInstance = clientClass.getConstructor(new Class[0]).newInstance(new Object[0]);
              Class[] tempClasses = new Class[1];
              tempClasses[0] = Bundle.class;
              Method onCreateMethod = clientClass.getDeclaredMethod("onCreate", tempClasses);
              onCreateMethod.setAccessible(true);
              Object[] tempObjects = new Object[1];
              tempObjects[0] = new Bundle();
              onCreateMethod.invoke(clientInstance, tempObjects);
          }
```

can someone help me ? I'll very appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Your code is also broken, doing things like having the absolute path "/mnt/sdcard" in it.

Comment: the APK_PATH = ""/mnt/sdcard/target.apk"

Comment: Yes that is broken.  Very broken.  The path to the SD card is found using the Environment class.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not possible.